# Adding nomenclature in winedt 8

Tags: nomenclature, winedt

i don't succeed to add nomenclature in my Phd thesis 
i used winedt 8, I have used the package nomencl. in my code I have incorporated the `\nomenclature` and `\printnomenclature` as well. But when I compile, it is not showing me any results.
I try to follow the instructions as the link: http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/Nomenclature.php
but no results
an idea please,
thank you,

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex`, `Make Nomenclature` (in the TeX menu) and then again `pdflatex`? Or simply use `PDFTeXify`.

Comment: "make nomenclature" is not yet available in my Tex menu, i don't know why?

Comment: You said you followed instructions given in the link in your question. Then the menu item should be there. Otherwise, the Nomenclature package isn't installed properly. Have you tried `PDFTeXify`? It should take care of running everything.

Comment: can you provide a MWE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the macro file Install.edt in WinEdt, and execute it by choosing Macros | Execute Current Macro.

You can find it here:
http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/Nomenclature.php

Good luck